# Running apache beam spark runner failed with java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Tags: go, sdk, apache-beam

I'm trying to run grades example of apache beam go sdk using apache beam spark runner.
I start the JobService endpoint on a pre-deployed spark cluster from apache beam go source using the following command:  `./gradlew :runners:spark:job-server:runShadow -PsparkMasterUrl=spark://localhost:7077` and,
i submit the job as follows: `grades =runner=spark -endpoint=host:port -job_name=xxxx`
I got the following error :

```
: Ruuning apache beam spark runner failed with java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for command 'docker run -d --network=host --env=DOCKER_MAC_CONTAINER=null 
apache/beam_go_sdk:latest --id=4-1 --provision_endpoint=localhost:*****
```

In qddition, docker is running and the dependencies are installed.

I found the following error also

```
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for command 'docker run -d --network=host --env=DOCKER_MAC_CONTAINER=null apache/beam_go_sdk:latest --id=2-1 --provision_endpoint=localhost:49392'
```

How can i proceed?

Comment: Is there a Java stack trace for the TimeoutException, or any other relevant logs? Otherwise it could be difficult to determine why the command timed out.

Comment: when running  journalctl -u docker, I found the follwing msg                                      `level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock                                                                                                level=info msg="ignoring event" container=6626c6c94c748c3b7b6`

Comment: `Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException:`

Comment: @ibzib I really need your help. I cannot figure out the problem here. I got the same error in some workers where other worker successfully worked.

Comment: Can you share more details about the Spark cluster you are running this on? E.g. is it a standalone cluster running on your computer, or a remote cluster using some sort of cluster manager?

Comment: I run it in a distributed cluster ( Master VM  and 3 Worker's VM installed in VMware connected via SSH)

Comment: After pulling go-apache.beam image manually in all VMs using apache/beam_go_sdk:latestm i got the following error:    `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No container running for id a1fdb8afb7b8c4a497c22270b7bb9678c2`  but the container is created

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your job server is unable to find the Docker image for the Go SDK. Here are some options:

#### Local Image

You can get the `apache/beam_go_sdk:latest` image on your local machine. You can pull the container from Docker Hub with the following command.

```
docker pull apache/beam_go_sdk:latest
```

Alternatively, you can build it yourself with the following command from the root directory of the Apache Beam repository.

```
./gradlew :sdks:go:container:docker
```

#### Loopback

Loopback mode is a shortcut to aid running pipelines locally for testing purposes. When you enable loopback mode, instead of the job server spinning up a Docker container to run the SDK code, it will instead loop requests back to the process you originally ran to create and submit the pipeline. This way you don't rely on Docker at all.

You can enable loopback mode by adding the pipeline option `--environment_type=LOOPBACK` when running your Beam pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I run it using local image and --environment_type=LOOPBACK  I get the following error  `/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam/io/filesystem/gcs/gcs.go:27:2: cannot find package "cloud.google.com/go/storage" in any of:
 /root/Projects/Proj1/src/github.com/apache/beam/vendor/cloud.google.com/go/storage (vendor tree)
 /usr/local/go/src/cloud.google.com/go/storage (from $GOROOT)
 /root/Projects/Proj1/src/cloud.google.com/go/storage (from $GOPATH)
...... `

Comment: Did you install dependencies using `go install [path_to_your_pipeline]`? (As described in the [Go SDK quickstart](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-go/))

Comment: Yes I installed dependencies qs described in GO sdk